# DB Schema not generated: illegalargumentexception unknown entity on Play Framework 2.4 + JPA Hibernate + Heroku

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, heroku, playframework-2.4

I have a problem which bothers me for few days now. I am developing a Play 2.4.0 Java application using JPA Hibearnate. Locally (Foreman) everything works fine and hibernate automatically creates schema, tables etc.

However, schema and tables are not generated on Heroku and I get this exception when accessing the app (GET test-app/):

```
 @6naopal00 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
 at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.
lay.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: assets.EndUser]
 at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]

 at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4
 at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261) ~[com.typesafe.p
 at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:215) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
 at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.1
 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [com.typesafe.play.play-iterat
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHand

 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar
 at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvok
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHand

 at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.ja
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2
 at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:159) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.
aused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: assets.EndUser
 at play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar
 at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:28) ~[test-investpal.test-investpal-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized
 at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:16) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.2.ja
 at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1184) ~[org.hibernate.hibe
 at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:136) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.2.ja
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [com.typesafe.akka
 at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.1
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-libra
 at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.
 at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:95) ~[test-investpal.t
 at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.pla
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.lambda$call$5(TransactionalAction.java:19) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-java-jpa_2.11
 at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2
 at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:95) ~[test-investpal.t
 at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.pla
 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.
 at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-libra
 at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11
 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2
 at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.
 at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11
 at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[com.typesafe.pla
 at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_
 ... 6 common frames omitted
```

This is my build.sbt:

```
 name := """test-app"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final"
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

fork in run := true
```

This is my conf/application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
db.default.logStatements=true
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"
```

This is my application controller:

```
package controllers;

import assets.EndUser;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.db.jpa.Transactional;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.main;

public class Application extends Controller {

    @Transactional
    public Result index() {

        EndUser endUser = new EndUser();

        endUser.setEmail("test@gmail.com");

        JPA.em().persist(endUser);

        return ok(main.render("Test App", "Your new application is ready."));
    }

}
```

This is my asset/entity:

```
package assets;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EndUser")
public class EndUser {
    public static final String ENTITY_NAME = "EndUser";
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Anyone knows how to force hibernate/persistence unit to generate schema, tables on Heroku? I also tried to manually create table, but hibernate is throwing same exception, not beaing able to find entity EndUser

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. It is documented on Play Migration https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Distribution

Simply add `PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false` to your build.sbt.

Issue is also discussed here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4590

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem without explicitly defining models in persistence.xml. In my case I had multiple persistence.xml one in root project and one in sub module. Once I removed this from root project I was able to run it successfully. See [here](http://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5092)